# Access functions in link section of Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Below is a directive I am trying to test. I know how I am going to test it but I am having a hard time finding out how to call/trigger the functions in the link section in order to start testing it(ie. scope.accountClick ).

I was sure I would be able to do it like :

```
it('should call selectProfile()', function () {
            jasmine.createSpy('selectProfile');
            scope().profileClick(account, property, profile);
            expect(scope.selectProfile).toHaveBeenCalledWith(account, property, profile);
        });
```

But it does not get called. Someone suggested I needed to use `element.isolateScope().profileClick(account, property, profile);` but that does not work either

The directive I am testing looks like this:

```
angular.module('pb.webSites.directives')
        .directive('pbGoogleAnalyticsManagementList', ['$window', '$document', function ($window, $document) {

            return {
                restrict: "E",
                templateUrl: "app/webSites/directives/GoogleAnalyticsManagementList.html",
                scope: {
                    googleAnalyticsProfile: '=pbGoogleAnalyticsProfile',
                    selectProfileFn: '&pbSelectProfile'
                },
                controller: 'GoogleAnalyticsManagementController',

                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                    scope.accountClick = function (account) {
                        //bunch of code

                        scope.getProperties(account);
                    };

                    scope.propertyClick = function (account, property) {
                        //bunch of code

                        scope.getProfiles(account, property);
                    };

                    scope.profileClick = function (account, property, profile) {
                        //bunch of code

                        scope.selectProfile(account, property, profile);
                    };
                }
            };
        }]);
```

Comment: You could try something like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/0ybrvp8s/1/). In this test I also use `isolateScope` and it works well. Your problem maybe because of setting up the `directive` inside `unit test` wrongly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `scope.selectProfileFn` inside `scope.profileClick`?

Comment: @themyth92 I didnt notice the link. this helps immensely. If you want to add it as an answer I will mark it as right